# How to create a filter component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There are hundreds of articles and code snippets on the internet. But I'm sorry that I'm not able to implement any one of them correctly. I've followed these study materials:

1. [Filtering in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035545/filtering-in-angular-js)
2. [Filtering in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254323/filtering-in-angular)
3. [Angular filters: w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_filter.asp)
4. [JavaScript Array filter() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

I also came across: `ng-repeat="data in myController.data | filter:{filterFlag:'true'}"`. But I don't understand this approach.

Instead of pasting the code here I thought creating a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3phby) will be more helpful.

I also tried understanding the concept from [this](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/myportal-complete/blob/master/src/components/ArticlesFrame.js) code. But this was ReactJs code so I got myself more confused.

I'm not getting any error or warning. My code returns the entire array (from which I'm trying to filter) or nothing at all. I'm not able to the understand the concept very well.

Dear community, don't write the code for me. but please point out my mistakes or suggest so that I can correct them.

The filter should work for both `username` or `location` (so that I can show all users who belong to same location).

Comment: capture the input values in your search function and then filter USER array using that value.

Comment: Yes. you're right. Actually i just removed all the code so that you people can see a clean code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuuxof check this I modified your project

Comment: you can use `lodash` also library also

Comment: Read through this.. All you need is on this page https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @MaxySpark, Sir your code is working. But it should work for location also. And that too irrespective of the upper or lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  /* an array of user objects*/
  users=[
    { id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", location: "India" },
    { id: 2, name: "Ervin Howell", username: "Antonette", location: "Australia" },
    { id: 3, name: "Clementine Bauch", username: "Samantha", location: "China" },
    { id: 4, name: "Patricia Lebsack", username: "Karianne", location: "On_my_couch" },
    { id: 5, name: "Chelsey Dietrich", username: "Kamren", location: "America" },
    { id: 6, name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist", username: "Leopoldo_Corkery", location: "Peru" },
    { id: 7, name: "Kurtis Weissnat", username: "Elwyn.Skiles", location: "China" },
    { id: 8, name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V", username: "Maxime_Nienow", location: "India" },
    { id: 9, name: "Glenna Reichert", username: "Delphine", location: "India" },
    { id: 10, name: "Clementina DuBuque", username: "Moriah.Stanton", location: "America" }
  ];
  text = '';

  constructor() { }

  // findUsers(username) {
  //   return user => username; 
  // }

 searchFunction(text) {
  console.log( this.users.filter(e => {
    return e.username.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase() ||
            e.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            || e.location.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase() ||
            e.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ;
  }));
}

  ngOnInit() { 
  }
}
```

**card.component.html**

```
<p>
card works!
</p>


<input type="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]='text'>
<button (click)="searchFunction(text)">Search</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuuxof)

Comment: this is 100% working. Can you please spare a few minutes to explain this. Only the `searchFunction()`.

Comment: Array filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: indexOf string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: And you're doing a two-way binding here: `[(ngModel)]='text'` right ?

Comment: Hi MAxySpark, I've replaced `users=[];` array with a fetch call to an api. Can you tell me how to initially show all the records on the screen. Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrn5xb

Comment: I mean. The filrered records will be shown on click. But initially all the records should be displayed. Right now it is just empty screen until something is searched.

Comment: Inside `ngOnInit()`, along with `this.users=json` i should also do `this.filteredUsers=json`. Solved! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the mistakes you do:

1. The value you enter in to search is not bound to a variable in your component. Let's bind it to the `searchText` variable.

   ```
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]='searchText'>
   ```
2. Your `filter` callback function can be declared as an Arrow function right within the `filter` call. This will let you access your search string via `this` and write the search comparator right there.

   If you still want your callback function to be a conventional function outside the `filter` call, `bind` it with the component context.

   ```
   console.log( this.users.filter(this.findUsers.bind(this)));
   ```

   This will enable the callback function to access the `this` context of the component.
3. Now write the correct filter string.

   ```
   return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchText.toLowerCase()) >= 0
   ```

Comment: I'll remember this throughout my career. Thank you Sir. I appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it but it should work. Give it a try

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" #searchtext>
<button (click)="searchFunction(searchtext.value)">Search</button>
```

COMPONENT

```
searchFunction(search) {
console.log( this.users.filter(value=> {
return value.username == search || value.location == search
}));
```

}

Comment: No sir. It is returning all usernames and all the locations.